# picutre srcset with webp fallback and different screen sizes

Tags: html, css, image, webp

When I want to use webp images when the browser supports it and otherwise fallback to jpg I use like this:

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="image.webp" type="image/webp" />
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="Something">
</picture>
```

also to choose the suitable image size for the screen size:

```
<picture>
    <source media="(max-width: 799px)" srcset="small.jpg">
    <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="big.jpg">
    <img src="big.jpg" alt="something">
</picture>
```

As I have all images, with all sizes and both formats, I want to do both of the features above at the same time, so I have both webps of small and big sizes and both jpgs of big and small sizes. So If the browser supports webp, only use webp images of different sizes (based on screen size) and if not use jpg files of different sizes.

I wonder if this is possible.

I Tested it like this:

```
<picture>
    <source media="(max-width: 799px)" srcset="small.webp">
    <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="big.webp">
    <source media="(max-width: 799px)" srcset="small.jpg">
    <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="big.jpg">
    <img src="big.jpg" alt="something">
</picture>
```

but it only chooses the first one matching the screen size

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the type attribute on each `source`, so the browser will be able to load the best format it understands, e.g.:

```html
<picture>
    <source media="(max-width: 799px)" srcset="small.webp" type="image/webp">
    <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="big.webp" type="image/webp">
    <source media="(max-width: 799px)" srcset="small.jpg" type="image/jpeg">
    <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="big.jpg" type="image/jpeg">
    <img src="big.jpg" alt="something">
</picture>
```

Comment: for some reason, media attribute breaks the behavior for me. Testing in chrome: when i do the same structure without media attribute in sources - i see big.webp picture. Once I add media attribute - i start to see big.jpeg picture. But I expect to see big.webp. not sure what is wrong

Comment: When you use the `media` attribute, you must use it with `srcset`. You may be trying it with simple `src`, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible. And it is pretty simple to be honest

```html
<img src="images/keyboard.webp" onerror="this.src='images/keyboard.jpg';"  alt="Image not found"/>
```

This code pretty much explains itself.

It loads `webp` image. `onerror` handles if image is not loaded. it sets `src` to `jpg`

Comment: i want to be able to define different webp images with different sizes and also different jpg images with different sizes.

Comment: I think that you will find your answer [here](https://internetingishard.com/html-and-css/responsive-images/)

It is in-depth explanation of how this works. If you have anything unclear come back here so we can resolve it :)